# Phonegap audio stops after playing 8 times

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, audio

I have a simple mobile app designed using PhoneGap. I am some mp3 in it and I am using the Media plugin of PhoneGap. Everything is working fine, the audio is playing and so on.

The issue, I noticed after playing 8-12 times, the audio stops playing. I do not get sound. Here are my codes:

**JavaScript**

```
<script>

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {

    }

    // Audio player
    var media = null;
    var audioP = false;


    // Play audio
    function playAudio(src) {
        if (audioP === false) {
        media = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);
        media.play();
        audioP = true;

    } else {
        media.release();
        }
    }

    // onSuccess Callback
    function onSuccess() {
        console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
        audioP = false;
    }

    // onError Callback
    function onError(error) {

    }      
    </script>
```

Help please!

Comment: What does Android console log says? It looks like a buffer problem. Also where is the code you wrote that is relevant to the looping/ repeat function.

Comment: Hi, I m sorry, what do you mean by Android console? I am developing this using a text editor. I think the media.release() is wrongly placed...